# Background image resize in CSS3PIE

Tags: css, image

Hello I'm trying to create same effect in IE8 as on this picture (works on FF 15 and Chrome but not on IE8)

[Comparison http://imageshack.us/a/img526/4466/10274965.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img526/4466/10274965.jpg)

In my code I used 2 images pa.png (190px x 500px) and ad.jpg (210px x 50px). As you can see on the image PIE  changed border-radius but did not scale the image.

I have a index.php file wchich is included from left.php

My code is

```
        <div id="lefti1">
        <div id="adm1" >
             <p class="m1">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus koniec</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And CSS

```
#lefti1 {
width:210px;
background: url(pa.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
background-size:210px 100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0px 0px;
position:relative;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
border-radius:16px 16px 16px 16px;
-pie-background: url(pa.png) no-repeat 50% 50% / 210px 100%;   
}   
.m1    {
text-align:justify;
margin:0 auto;
padding:55px 10px;
}
#adm1 {
width:210px;
height:auto;
background: transparent url(ad.jpg) no-repeat center 0px;
background-size:210px 50px;
border-radius:16px 16px 0 0;
border:none;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);    
}
```

Iwanto to scale  the *pa.png* to fill *div id="lefti1"*. I tried to add a *.htaccess* file, *background-size:cover* but nothing helped. 
Can anybody see and point me my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background

> […] the following aspects of the background shorthand will currently be
>   ignored when rendering in IE 6-8:
>
> - background-size (will always use the image's intrinsic size)

Comment: OK thanks for the answer. Is there another posibility to get the same results in IE8 as in FF and Chrome?

Comment: now reads `background-size (will always use the image's intrinsic size) — this is supported as of PIE 2.0 beta` - allthough i'm not getting it to work yet.